# Inner Join in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I have two tables

front_employee (Employee model in Django)

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name            | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description     | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| employee_img_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| language_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And front_employeepicture (EmployeePicture in Django)

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| img   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to perform this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.img
FROM front_employee a
INNER JOIN front_employeepicture b
ON a.employee_img_id = b.id
```

For now I have

```
context['employee'] = Employee.objects.all().order_by('order')
```

And I tried something like

```
context['employee'] = Employee.objects.select_related('EmployeePicture')
```

Without result. Any idea?

Comment: You'll need to show your models. Generally, Django handles inner joins for you via `ForeignKey` fields - this will be trivial if you've set up your models correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's ORM is really powerful. You actually don't have to do joins like that, ever. When you access the field, the ORM performs the join on the fly, returning the result you want.

```
first_employee = Employee.objects.all().first()
employee_picture = first_employee.employee_img
```

And then employee_picture should have the picture of the first employee. It needed to internally do an inner join to figure that out, but Django hides all that for you. (I may have gotten your variable names wrong, sorry).

What `select_related` does is pre-fetch a relation for every object in a queryset. That means less trips back and forth to the database, which makes your functions faster. But, Django allows you to traverse relationships just by accessing attributes.

Try messing around with this stuff in your django shell. I would add django_extensions to your app (`pip install django-extensions`, then add `django_extensions` to your INSTALLED_APPS, then run `python manage.py shell_plus`). And if not, `python manage.py shell` works fine, but you have to import your models manually.

Comment: If part of this is filtering to only employees that have images, use Employee.objects.filter(employee_img__isnull=False). And finally, Django's documentation is really good. I would read through as much of that as you can, if you haven't yet.